# How can I query on the year part of a complete date in a custom field?

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, date

My posts have a custom field named *production*_date and formatted YYYYMMDD.

How can I form a meta_query to select only the YYYY part?

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'production_date',
        'value'   => '2004',
        'compare' => '???'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handy thing about how ACF stores dates as `YYYYMMDD` is you can treat them like integers and get a similar level of functionality as if you were using "true" dates.

For example, to get all dates after 1st Jan 2011, use `> 20110101`. Those before June 1st 2012? `< 20120601`. And for your case, all dates within 2004? `>= 20040101 && <= 20041231`.

Translated into a meta query:

```
$year = '2004';

$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'production_date',
        'value'   => array( $year . '0101', $year . '1231' ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    )
);
```

[Check out the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) for a full explanation of all the arguments.

Answer (score -1):

You could use PHP's [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions to get a year:

```
$date_value = '20040619'; // from your production_date custom field

$year = date( 'Y', strtotime( $date_value ) );

$meta_query_args = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'production_date',
        'value'   => $year,
        'compare' => '???'
    )
);
```

Comment: The `???` in the question means "what do I put here?". this won't work and does not answer the question of trying to query values stored as a full date by year.

Comment: @squarecandy wow, I wonder if I just forgot to figure that out before posting. Good catch! My answer is trash lol